# Query that counts all items in joined table

Tags: sql

I have three tables:

Account:

```
AccountId | AccountEmail
```

PurchasedProducts:

```
ProductName | AccountId | ProductTypeId
```

ProductTypes:

```
ProductTypeId | ProductTypeName
```

I want to make a query that counts the number of purchased products per producttype per account. It should look something like this:

```
AccountEmail  | ProductTypeName A | ProductTypeName B | ProductTypeName C
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
peter@test.nl | 0                 | 12                | 1
```

I can't figure out how to make this query... Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Will it always be 3 product types a b and c?

Comment: My DBMS is Ms SQL Azure (v12)

Comment: Sorry Sagi... No the productTypes are dynamic. They change over time.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will work

```
SELECT accountemail, 
       Sum(CASE 
             WHEN producttypename = 'ProductTypeName A' THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
           END) AS 'ProductTypeName A', 
       Sum(CASE 
             WHEN producttypename = 'ProductTypeName B' THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
           END) AS 'ProductTypeName B', 
       Sum(CASE 
             WHEN producttypename = 'ProductTypeName C' THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
           END) AS 'ProductTypeName C' 
FROM   purchasedproducts p 
       INNER JOIN producttypes ot 
               ON p.producttypeid = pt.producttypeid 
       INNER JOIN account a 
               ON a.accountid = p.accountid 
WHERE  producttypename IN ( 'ProductTypeName A', 'ProductTypeName B', 
                            'ProductTypeName C' ) 
GROUP  BY accountemail
```

Comment: Will only work incase he has 3 products type.. if not he needs to pivot

Comment: @sagi That can be done when OP clarifies which Database he/she is using

Comment: Sagi, I think you are on the right track but those productnames should be dynamic as well (maybe by s subquery)...

Comment: As stated above, the DBMS is Ms Sql Azure v12

Answer (score 0):

The following (based on @VR46 's answer) will give the right values, but not in the exact table format the OP presented. I think, this should suffice for most uses, and in the case a `producttype` per column format is needed, a **pivot table** can be created with Excel or another query.

```
SELECT accountemail, producttypename, COUNT(*)
FROM   purchasedproducts p 
       INNER JOIN producttypes ot 
               ON p.producttypeid = pt.producttypeid 
       INNER JOIN account a 
               ON a.accountid = p.accountid 
GROUP  BY accountemail, producttypename
```

Comment: I got that far myself. The problem is the table format. I can't use pivot tables because i want to display the results in a webpage. I can't process the table by code as well becasuse of a reporting framework i use...